# Regexp header_checks in postfix for a match over multiple lines

Tags: postfix, regex

Here's my /etc/postfix/main.cf header_checks line:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/maps/header_checks
```

And here is header_checks:

```
/From:.*email@my\.com.(\n|.)*?To:.*email@my\.com./     DISCARD
```

Here's portion of the header from the emails I'm trying to match:

```
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.server.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 690649204C0
    for <email@my.com>; Mon,  7 Nov 2022 13:27:00 -0600 (CST)
From: "White Carb Tricks" <email@my.com>
To: "email" <email@my.com>
Subject: Clear artery-blocking plaque overnight
Date: Mon, 7 Nov 2022 09:42:42 -0600
```

As you can see I'm trying to match when spammers spoof the "For" and the "To" to look like the user sent it.

If I test the regular expression in header_checks via an online regex tool it matches the "From" and "To" lines like I want.

[image: regex produces one match when applied to the full email headers]

When I do:

```
postmap -q $'From: "White Carb Tricks" <email@my.com>\r\nTo: "email" <email@my.com>' regexp:/etc/postfix/maps/header_checks
```

It returns "DISCARD" as expected.

When I paste the header text into a test file and test it like this:

```
postmap -q - regexp:/etc/postfix/maps/header_checks < /etc/postfix/maps/regex-test
```

...it returns blank.

I should note that Postfix isn't discarding them either. The user keeps getting the emails.

I also changed this in master.cf:

```
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

to

```
-o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_address_mappings
```

...based on another thread I read.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is it my regex in header_checks?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like that, as documented `man 5 header_checks` (emphasis mine):

> Note:  message  headers are examined **one logical header at a time**,
> even when a message header spans multiple lines. Body lines are always examined one line at a time.

You could have tested this by calling postmap as its meant to be:

```
# does not mimic header_checks, trues the whole lookup key.
postmap -q $'HA: value\r\nHB: value2' regexp:header_checks.pcre
# does mimic header_checks, one header (including continuation) at a time:
postmap -h -q $'HA: value\r\nHB: value2' regexp:header_checks.pcre
```

If you want to match multiple headers at once, plug in a tool fit for the purpose. Popular choices geared towards the spam fighting use case include SpamAssassin (dated, but still works) and Rspamd.

If you want people to stop using *your* domain name, look into [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC).

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I see why the headers in this case aren't being flagged. As far as DMARC, this client has a proper DMARC in place. The "From" in  question isn't from the "Received From" but is, instead the mail "From'" in the header. This seems to make a difference? Apparently  the DMARC grabs the From info from the "Received From". Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @Denny The result of the DMARC validation is the combination of a check whether the message is signed/sent by an an authorized party AND the header sender is aligned with what was checked. If the client has published and is enforcing a DMARC policy, and you are seeing email with that name spoofed in the `From:` header, you want to have a stern look at the `Authentication-Results:` headers.